# Download progress streaming with retrofit from Amazon

Tags: android, retrofit2

I have problem with stream downloading. @streaming annotation not worked as expected. I receive responseBody only after finish downloading. So I can't download file with streaming, because file downloaded in memory and then a receive it and save to cache directory.

My retrofit api:

```
public interface DownloadingAmazonApi {

@GET
@Streaming
Observable<ResponseBody> downloadFile(@Url String url);
}
```

Usage:

```
downloadingAmazonApi.downloadFile(url)
            .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .map(body -> writeResponseBodyToDisk(body, type))
            .map(localUrl -> ......))
            ...
```

Why @streaming not working? I tried to use different links (amazon and another hostings). I expect, that I will receive responseBody with stream immediately after start downloading and I will cache this stream into storage (without downloading into memory).

Comment: Also I tried to use this solutions: [this](https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-2-how-to-download-files-from-server) ,  [this](https://blog.playmoweb.com/view-download-progress-on-android-using-retrofit2-and-okhttp3-83ed704cb968)

Answer (score 2):

I dont know what is it. I remove HttpLoggingInterseptor and stream worked as expected